# JavaFx + Maven: no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, javafx, maven, eclipse, openjdk

Небольшой проект с использованием **OpenJFX** со сборщиком **Maven**. Проект запускается из **Eclipse**, но после создания и запуска **jar**-файла (используя `java -jar app.jar`) получаю такую ошибку: `no main manifest attribute in jar-file`.

Вот зависимости и плагины из `pom.xml`:

```
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
            <openjfx.version>14.0.2</openjfx.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
                <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
                <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
                <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>14</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>14</release>
                        <mainClass>top.jalva.tictactoe.App</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Пробовал добавлять еще и `maven-jar-plugin` c указанием `<manifest><mainClass>[path]</mainClass></manifest>`, но в этом случае получаю такую ошибку: `Error: Could not find or load main class [path] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно, то проще использовать 8 java, т.к. оттуда еще не вырезали javafx. Сборка и запуск проходит непринужденно)

Для более новых версий, начиная от 9:

- Это качаем sdk https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
- В `maven` добавляем `shade` плагин, который упакует как надо:

  ```
  <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.4</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <transformers>
                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                         <mainClass>com.lampa.App</mainClass>
                     </transformer>
                 </transformers>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Полный `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.lampa.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.lampa.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

и собираем через `mvn package`

Для запуска добавляем модули, которые используем в `dependencies`:

```
java --module-path C:/javafx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -jar sample-1.0.0.jar
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Вроде, запустилось, но теперь не находит файлы ресурсов. Т.е. библиотеку нужно передавать с дистрибутивом приложения? Jar-файл приложения не будет ее включать?

Comment: @alex valuiskyi вот на счет ресурсов не пробовал, скоро обновлю ответ

Comment: @alex valuiskyi библиотеку да, нужно размещать там, где будет запускаться. По поводу ресурсов, с таким же конфигом и ресурсами в src/main/resources/layout.fxml успешно загружается через `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/layout.fxml"))`

Comment: `Fxml` у меня грузится без проблем. А вот с загрузкой `Image` проблемы: `getClass().getResource("/image.png")` возвращает `null`

Comment: Попробуй добавить в `<build>`       `<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>` у меня помогло. Кст в jar'нике есть dll'ки, но вот как их добавить в модули я не разобрался пока