# Как исправить ошибку: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, maven

Делаю тестовый проект с JavaFX, SQLite, указывая соответствующие зависимости в `pom.xml`.  Также использую fxml, всё работает.
В процессе столкнулся с ошибкой, которую решил исправить отладчиком, но при запуске Debug появляется ошибка:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found
```

В качестве помощи использовал этот ресурс: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

1. Вопрос в следующем. Нашёл такой путь: `C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx`, там лежат `javafx-controls` и `javafx-fxml`, а также множество других модулей.
   Если я правильно понял, то именно их надо указывать в `Run-Edit Configurations-VM Options`

```
--module-path "C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

типо такого, но здесь нужно указать путь до самого модуля.

Если делаю так:

```
--module-path "C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15.0.1" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

то пишется ошибка, что не может найти `javafx-fxml`.
Вопрос, как указать два адреса, или как это обойти.

Скинул `pom.xml` на всякий случай

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pass-keeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>pass-keeper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>pass.App</mainClass>
                    <executable>E:\Develop Tools\Java JDK\bin\java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        App.Class
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывая

```
--module-path "C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15.0.1"
```

Вы ссылаетесь только на модуль `javafx-controls`

1 вариант: качаем весь sdk https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ и указываем типа: `--module-path C:/javafx/lib`

2 вариант если хочется указать несколько директорий: `--module-path dir1;dir2;dirN`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можете еще подсказать почему этих путей и зависимостей не было сначала, разве maven не подключает сам, или же я просто смог сбить настройки эти?

Comment: @ДимаВасильев там танцевать с бубном надо над этими модулями) я сам до конца не разобрался как их запихнуть в сборку, но почитайте еще вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248573/javafx-maven-no-main-manifest-attribute/1248972#1248972

Comment: Благодарю, спасли меня. Спасибо большое

Comment: @ДимаВасильев если ответ верный, то примите его как правильный пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже при запуске тестовой программы javaFx
выскакивали подобные сообщения об ошибке,пока я не добавил в проект библиотеки jdk-19.До этого у меня в
проекте были только библиотеки javafx-sdk-19.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/806581)