# Не открывается Jar файл

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar

Собрал Jar ник с JavaFx (8ая java)  при помощи maven-assembly-plugin. У меня на ноутбуке данный Jar запускается по дабл клику, но на других устройствах, дабл клик игнорируется, если попытаться открыть с помощью консоли, то падает данная ошибка:

```
$ java -jar DataValidation-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar Error: Could not find or load main class
sample.Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Как исправить?
Мой pom. Собираю jar командой mvn clean `compile assembly:single`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>DataValidation</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.albfernandez</groupId>
        <artifactId>juniversalchardet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: JDK один и тот же?

Comment: Гляньте через zip что в пакете лежит и также посмотрите этот топик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248573/javafx-maven-no-main-manifest-attribute/1248972#1248972